# how do i store date values in sqlite

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

i am currently trying to add a database to my WindowsForms code. the program currently asks the user for a date time input using a date picker. the data is then stored in a property of a class called `invoice` . i want this property of the class like all the other properties of the same class to be added as a column in the database. how would i add this as sqlite doesn't support datetime data structures. note: i am a beginning programmer which is why i'm using sqlite rather than a sql server.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data which you are trying to sort?

Comment: @H.S if you have 4 invoices on the 21.08.21 and 3 invoices on 24.08.21 and you then choose a range on 20.08.21 -- 25.08.21 it should return the index of all 7 invoices if that makes sense

Comment: Use LINQ with a `Where` method call to filter the `List`. You need to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FindAll` to achieve your result.

`var filterObjects = lstInvoices.FindAll(x => x.InvoiceDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) && x.InvoiceDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));`

**Complete Example**

*Invoice Class*

```
 public class Invoice
    {
        public Invoice(int id, DateTime invoiceDate)
        {
            Id = id;
            InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    }
```

*Insert dummy data*

```
var lstInvoices = new List<Invoice>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lstInvoices.Add(new Invoice(1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i + 5)));
            lstInvoices.Add(new Invoice(2, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i + 5)));
            lstInvoices.Add(new Invoice(3, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i + 5)));
        }
```

*Filter records today-2 to today+2*

```
var filterObjects = lstInvoices.FindAll(x => x.InvoiceDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) && x.InvoiceDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
```

**`filterObjects` contain your desire result**